# Прозрачный статус бар

Tags: android, java

Сделал статус бар прозрачным, но теперь статус бар прозрачный и такие элементы как часы и уведомления поверх тулбара, как можно сделать прозрачным статус бар, чтобы к примеру и выдвигаемое боковое меню было на статус баре и еще чтобы часы и уведомления были выше тулбара как бы в своем баре, что то типа добавить статус бар, который

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20fullscreen%20activity&es_th=1

Comment: @metalurgus я так делал весь экран, для меня не то, я хочу, чтобы еще статус бар был, но когда я ставлю  
    
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

но теперь у меня часы видны, но они поверх тулбара, на котором у меня элементы есть, потому хочу, чтобы как и часы были у себя на статус баре с заданным цветом, но еще и боковое меню было поверх статус бара, но не поверх часов

Comment: @metalurgus хотелось бы как у него но не понял как он сделал

Comment: @eldqs, я тоже не знаю, как "он" сделал. Я даже не знаю ,кто "он".

Comment: @metalurgus извиняюсь, забыл  https://camo.githubusercontent.com/7980935031c7594c8f9de5bb2ff6c56f79e1f502/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6e656f6b7265652f4d6174657269616c4e617669676174696f6e4472617765722f6d61737465722f6172742f73637265656e332e6a7067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В примитивном случае нужно задавать верхний отступ(margin_top) toolbar равный высоте статус бара.
Для удобного использования(написания кода) у navigation drawer вам не нужно задавать отступ, а у основного контента фрагмента или активити нужно задавать.
Другого решения нет.

Чтобы получить высоту статус бара, можно воспользоваться этим примером

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(final Context context)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0)
        {
            result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @andreich сделал, как вы написали, margin_top, но не подходит, надо, как по ссылке

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/7980935031c7594c8f9de5bb2ff6c56f79e1f502/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6e656f6b7265652f4d6174657269616c4e617669676174696f6e4472617765722f6d61737465722f6172742f73637265656e332e6a7067

Comment: я сам делал так, как описал в ответе, все подходит. просто делайте правильно все.

Comment: @andreich правильно ли я делаю

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
                android:margin_top="20dp"

пока назначаю 20dp,

Comment: лучше делать программно

Comment: @andreich вы смотрели ссылку, там боковое меню поверх статус бара, но action bar ниже под статус баром.

Comment: смотрел, я вам и сказал, что такое делал

Comment: можно и в гугле найти
https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20navigation%20drawer%20over%20actionbar&es_th=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745300/navigation-drawer-semi-transparent-over-status-bar-not-working